# Delete brackets and numbers via Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How do I delete automatically the brackets and the numbers?

Example:

```
[132]
[100]
[1011]
```

How can I delete with Notepad++?

Comment: Do you want to delete also spaces/linebreak before/after? Please show some sample text and expected result.

Comment: Hi, Alex and thanks for your post. Are you trying to delete this using code? Search and replace? A little more detail would be really handy if possible. Thanks.

Comment: sure so i need delte this regular Brackets and Numbers [1011] now solution founded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the Replace dialog, then enter `\[\d+\]` in the "Find what" box, and make sure regular expressions are used as search mode.

By clicking `Replace All`, Notepad++ will remove all instances of square brackets with one or more digits in between.