# Regular Expression Not Showing Results in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I built an expression to find any instances of '[###]' in Notepad++ for a given file:
[1]0x0a[22]0xbb[33]0xcc

and replace them with whitespace.  Seems easy enough...

```
(\[[0-9]\]|\[[0-9][0-9]\]|\[[0-9][0-9][0-9]\])
```

and permutations of

```
/(\[[0-9]\]|\[[0-9][0-9]\]|\[[0-9][0-9][0-9]\])g
```

They did not yield any matches.

I tested this out on http://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html and it worked as expected.

Am I missing some nuance for Regex in Notepad++?     And, yes, I did have Search mode set for "Regular Expression".

My question is not a duplicate of this one: [Delete brackets and numbers via Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819534/delete-brackets-and-numbers-via-notepad)

My Regex works, just not in the version of Notepad++ I am using.

Comment: Works for me. Have you checked `Regular expression`? Have a try with - Find: `\[\d+\]` and Replace: `A space`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[\d+\]`
- Replace with: `A SPACE`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[      # opening bracket
\d+     # 1 or more digits
\]      # closing bracket
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you.  Any suggestion on why my regex didn't work in Notepad, but worked fine on the test website?

Comment: @JeffreyMcNeal: It should work, have you checked `Regular expression` as shown in above screen shot?

Comment: Yes...  I mentioned that in the last sentence of my question.

Comment: @JeffreyMcNeal: Well.. I've just try your regex instead of mine and I get it work pretty fine. I don't understand why you can't make it working ;( May be you have some “strange” characters.

Comment: @JeffreyMcNeal: Or may be a version problem, here I'm using v7.8.7 64-bit

Comment: That has to be it then: I am using v7.5.9 64-bit.  Thanks again for the help.